# Flutter: Add padding to only certain elements in my ListView

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview, padding, listtile

I'm trying to create a ListView and would only want the first item to be padded. Here is the code:

```
Expanded(
     child: ListView.builder(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
       itemCount: card.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       if (index == 0) {
           return MyCard.buildRecordCard(
            card[index], context);
       } else {
          return MyCard.buildRecordsCards(
            card[index], context, index);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

The output looks as follows: [image: current output]

but I want cards 2...n (i.e. index != 0) not to be padded and to stretch out to the end of the screen. Something like this:

```
if (index == 0) {
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    return MyCard.buildRecordCard(
      card[index], context);
} else {
    padding: 0,
    return MyCard.buildRecordsCards(
       card[index], context, index);
}
```

but that obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to wrap the widget with [`Padding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html).
simply you can use ternary like

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Padding(
      padding: index == 0 ? EdgeInsets.all(16) : EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: MyCard.buildRecordCard(card[index], context));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I just added the padding to the item I was building by wrapping it in a container as follows:

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
        child: ...ListTile...
```